# Best way format user input before storing it (C)?

Tags: c, scanf

so I'm very new to C and I'm writing a program that takes user input and splits it into two i.e.

```
>char beforeColon;
>char afterColon[35];
>user enters: "u:some stuff"
>beforeColon = 'u'
>afterColon = "some stuff"
```

Basically, I would like to store `u` in one char variable and `some stuff` in a `char` array, but so far I've only been able to achieve it by using a `char` array for `beforeColon` as well. I also was wondering if it would work if I change `beforeColon` to an int so i can just get the ASCII of the `char` entered by the user.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char afterColon[35];
    char  beforeColon[2];
    int ASCII_of_bc;
    scanf("%1s:%[^\n]s", beforeColon, afterColon);
    ASCII_of_bc = beforeColon[0];
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: "%1s" will read a string, i.e., there'll be a nul character appended. Thus `beforeColon` becomes `['u', '\0']`. Read a single character instead: "%c".

Comment: The final `s` serves no purpose in`"%1s:%[^\n]s"`.  Best to add width limit --> `"%1s:%34[^\n]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[strtok()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)** function:

```
char user_enters[13]= "u:some stuff";
char *ret_pointer=NULL;

ret_pointer = strtok(user_enters, ":");

if(ret_pointer){    
    //Get the beforeColon character set <ret_pointer>
}
ret_pointer = strtok(NULL, ":");  

if(ret_pointer){
    //Get the afterColon character set <ret_pointer>
}
```

Comment: Curious: why initialize `char *ret_pointer=NULL;` and then assign it right away?  Consider `char *ret_pointer = strtok(user_enters, ":");` as a concise alternative.

Comment: Yes you can do it. As far as I am aware it is not mandatory to declare variable separately. But I think it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char afterColon[35];
    char beforeColon;
    int ASCII_of_bc;

    scanf("%c:%s", &beforeColon, afterColon);
    ASCII_of_bc = (int) beforeColon;
}
```

Reference:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/